# tftp error code 2 access violation (tftp not working)

Tags: server, permissions, tftp

**System info:**

```
Linux ravi-Inspiron-N5010 3.13.0-46-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10
20:08:14 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

I am struggling to run tftp localhost.

Tried:

```
root@ravi-Inspiron-N5010:/home/ravi/Desktop# service tftpd-hpa restart
tftpd-hpa stop/waiting
tftpd-hpa start/running
root@ravi-Inspiron-N5010:/home/ravi/Desktop# service tftpd-hpa status
tftpd-hpa start/running
```

Now I get error:

```
root@ravi-Inspiron-N5010:/home/ravi/Desktop# tftp 127.0.0.1
tftp> put test
Error code 2: Access violation
tftp>
```

permission of the file I am trying to put is :

```
root@ravi-Inspiron-N5010:/home/ravi/Desktop# ls -ld test 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ravi ravi 0 Mar 21 20:09 test
```

Permission of the /tftpboot folder:

```
root@ravi-Inspiron-N5010:/# ls -ld  tftpboot/
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody root 4096 Mar 15 15:34 tftpboot/
```

**Additional Information**

```
root@ravi-Inspiron-N5010:/home/ravi/Desktop# nano /etc/xinetd.d/tftp

service tftp


{
   protocol = udp
   port = 69
   socket_type = dgram
   wait = yes
   user = nobody
   server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
   server_args = /tftpboot -s
   disable = no
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The file you want to put via tftp must exist in the destination directory, and have permissions allowing it to be overwritten. For your instance, `test` must exist in `/tftpboot`.

You can see the reason in the tftp man page BUGS section.

I'm struggling to solve how to put a new file via tftp, but still don't know how.

Comment: Use "-c" argument to support create new file, if you are using tftpd-hpa

Comment: as @alfred mentioned below, not all tftpd implementations supports '-c‘

Answer (score 4):

Check `syslog` and you will see that :

```
 tftpd: serving file from /srv/tftp
```

Basically there is a bug and you will need in your case to move all files from the folder `/tftpboot` to `/srv/tftp` (make the folder `/srv/tftp` if doens't exist) and make sure you give 777 permissions and to all file inside, restart `xinetd` and it will works!

Comment: Your answer helped me solve this problem. But I solved it by modifying `/etc/inetd.conf`

Answer (score 2):

This could be because 14.04 has a `tftp` server setting in `/etc/inetd.conf`:

```
#BOOT: TFTP service is provided primarily for booting.  Most sites
#       run this only on machines acting as "boot servers."
tftp    dgram  udp wait    nobody  /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/in.tftpd /srv/tftp
```

you can comment out this line and try again.

I got this from here:
http://www.beer.org/blog/tftpd-and-xinetd-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 2):

As leondgarse mention, you cannot upload new files directly with your settings. But you can add "-c" to server_args, like:

```
service tftp
{
   protocol = udp
   port = 69
   socket_type = dgram
   wait = yes
   user = nobody
   server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
   server_args = -c -s /tftpboot
   disable = no
}
```

For detail, you can see man page of "in.tftpd":

```
   --create, -c
          Allow new files to be created.  By default, tftpd will only allow upload of files that already exist.  Files are created with default permissions allow‐
          ing anyone to read or write them, unless the --permissive or --umask options are specified.
```

Comment: Using xinetd I get the "unknown option -?" message in syslog. Is this solution for tftp-hba only?

Comment: @Noel, yes, not all tftpd implementation supports '-c‘

Answer (score 1):

In my case it (Debian 9.9) I resolve it by editing /etc/inetd.conf and modifying the line :

> tftp            dgram   udp     wait    nobody  /usr/sbin/tcpd 
>   /usr/sbin/in.tftpd **/srv/tftp**

by

> tftp            dgram   udp     wait    nobody  /usr/sbin/tcpd 
>   /usr/sbin/in.tftpd **/tftpboot**

The file "/etc/xinetd.d/tftp" was not reading.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is something with the design of TFTP but when doing a put it does not let you create a file.

Solution:

Create the file before hand and give 777 rights. Run transfer again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the files mode bits.

In my case, the tftp root directory is `/opt/tftpboot/`

Using `ls -l` command, I could see the file mode was 600, so when I try to access tftp to get this file with anonymous, it reports an access violation.

This may be the cause of this error. But there may be another reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshooting TFTPD Server on Ubuntu 14.0.4 by Dayanand Ambawade**

**Step-1: Edit /etc/inetd.conf**

*tftp    dgram  udp wait    nobody  /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/in.tftpd /srv/tftpboot*

**Step-2: Write script for tftpd**

*sudo nano /etc/xinetd.d/tftp*

service tftp

```
{
   protocol = udp
   port = 69
   socket_type = dgram
   wait = yes
   user = nobody
   server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
   server_args = /srv/tftpboot -s
   disable = no
}
```

**Step-3: Create Directory and set the permissions**

```
sudo mkdir /srv/tftpboot
sudo echo "Test TFTP Server" > /srv/tftpboot/test.txt
sudo chmod 777 -R /srv/tftpboot
sudo chown -R nobody.root /srv/tftpboot
```

**Step-4: Start service**

```
sudo service xinetd restart
sudo service inetutils-inetd restart
```

**Step-5: Test Server**

```
echo "get test.txt" | tftp 127.0.0.1
cat test.txt
Test TFTP Server
```

*Hopefully this will solve the problem.
Regards*